# How to replace '/' with ''?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code where I try and replace '/' with '' in an input element. But its not working. The '/' is not being replaced.

**How can I make it work?**

```js
var playlistTitle = document.getElementById('PlaylistTitleInput').value;
$('#PlaylistTitleInput').text($('#PlaylistTitleInput').text().replace("/", ''));
console.log(document.getElementById('PlaylistTitleInput').value);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fullPageBackgroundForPlaylistAdding" id="fullPageBackgroundForPlaylistAdding" style="display: none;">
  <!-- style="display: none;" -->
  <div class="addPlaylistElementsContainer">
    <h1 class="playlistLabel">Create new playlist</h1>
    <div class="PlaylistTitleInput">
      <input id="PlaylistTitleInput" type="text" name="playlistTitle" placeholder="New Playlist" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="cancel_CreateDiv">
      <button id="cancelBtnPress">Cancel</button><button id="createBtnPress">Create</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is `PlaylistTitleInput`? `input` element? Please add your `html` code.

Comment: Can you post a full [MCVE]? What sort of text exists there originally, and what are you expecting as output?

Comment: Its the ID of the input @random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` element value is accessed using `.val()` and not with `.text()`. Use regular expression `/\//g` to replace all occurrences of `/` with empty string.

```js
$('#PlaylistTitleInput').val($('#PlaylistTitleInput').val().replace(/\//g, ''));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="PlaylistTitleInput" value="abc/fjk/">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

```js
var playlistTitle = document.getElementById('PlaylistTitleInput').value;
$('#PlaylistTitleInput').val(playlistTitle.replace("/", ''));
console.log(document.getElementById('PlaylistTitleInput').value);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fullPageBackgroundForPlaylistAdding" id="fullPageBackgroundForPlaylistAdding" style="display: none;">
  <!-- style="display: none;" -->
  <div class="addPlaylistElementsContainer">
    <h1 class="playlistLabel">Create new playlist</h1>
    <div class="PlaylistTitleInput">
      <input id="PlaylistTitleInput" type="text" name="playlistTitle" placeholder="New Playlist" value="Test/123">
    </div>
    <div class="cancel_CreateDiv">
      <button id="cancelBtnPress">Cancel</button><button id="createBtnPress">Create</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the click.  Make a regex to match all forward slashes.  Replace the regex with your empty string.

```js
$('#createBtnPress').on('click', function() {
  var regex = /\//g;
  var formattedInput = $('#PlaylistTitleInput').val().replace(regex, '');
  $('#PlaylistTitleInput').val(formattedInput);
  console.log(formattedInput);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fullPageBackgroundForPlaylistAdding" id="fullPageBackgroundForPlaylistAdding">
  <!-- style="display: none;" -->
  <div class="addPlaylistElementsContainer">
    <h1 class="playlistLabel">Create new playlist</h1>
    <div class="PlaylistTitleInput">
      <input id="PlaylistTitleInput" type="text" name="playlistTitle" placeholder="New Playlist" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="cancel_CreateDiv">
      <button id="cancelBtnPress">Cancel</button>
      <button id="createBtnPress">Create</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```